# How do I create a bat file to convert video files in a folder using ffmpeg

Tags: windows-7, batch, ffmpeg

I would like to create a bat file that will go to a certain folder that contains video files, look for any files that are not .avi and convert them to .avi using ffmpeg.

I don't need, and don't want, to keep the original files, I just want them all converted to avi.

I'm using Windows 7. Please keep your answer very simple if you can because I am a complete novice.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd not bother with a .bat file and use a bit of software that supports watch folders.  As you're on windows, you could try DivX's suite which can handle conversion and supports watch folders;

http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus

There's an intro to the watch folders feature here;

http://labs.divx.com/node/121

Comment: Hmm.  Didn't get very far with this. The first link is for divx which I installed, only to discover that it is not Dr Divx described in the 2nd link.  The 2nd link is for Dr Divx, a different program, and suports 'watch folders'.  When trying to install Dr Divx it said it is not compatible with my OOS, I run Win 7.  I installed it anyway and ran it, it then said I need to install the latest divx codecs, presumably the ones I had just installed with the latest version of Divx, but for some reason doesn't recognise.  Shame really, it looked like a good solution.